# Why exception in child domain close program?

Tags: c#, exception, appdomain

Why exception in one application domain affect another application domain?

How do I prevent the closing of the program?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace domain
{
public class Worker : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public static void NotMyCodeThreadProc()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public void NotMyCode()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(NotMyCodeThreadProc);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");
        Worker remoteWorker = (Worker) ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "domain.Worker");
        try
        {
            remoteWorker.NotMyCode();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        Console.WriteLine("!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need a custom CLR host to change the unhandled exception policy.  You can't write on in C# code.  Google ICLRPolicyManager::SetDefaultAction()

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 2.0 (and above), an unhandled exception in a thread causes the entire process to terminate.

You can change that policy by following Hans' advice, or you can simply wrap your code with try/catch and handle the exception.